# PHPMyAdmin Fails After Updating to 4.8.4

Tags: wamp, phpmyadmin

After installing the [4.8.4 PHPMyAdmin plugin](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/apps/wampserver3_x86_x64_phpmyadmin4.8.4.exe) for [WampServer 3.6](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.1.6.exe), it either refuses to load or delivers the following screens: 
[image]
[image]
[image]

I use WampServer for testing/practice (and am currently working on a project), and thus would appreciate a timely fix. I am willing to downgrade my version if that is the problem.

Comment: Try to add this entry in the `autoload.php` file: `$autoload['config'] = array('twig');`

Comment: @harrymc I added the fix you suggested, and get a new error screen in return: https://i.imgur.com/iWdciID.png

Comment: @harrymc I sometimes get the original error screen. I get various errors, here they are: https://imgur.com/a/ri55Gkj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I can tell, the problem is that phpMyAdmin 4.8.4 supports PHP 7.2.x, and my installed PHP version is PHP 7.3. I installed PHP 7.2.13 and switched it to my default PHP installation and PHPMyAdmin started working properly.
[image]
I saw the above image when searching for an older version of phpMyAdmin to install in case the 4.8.4 update was the problem. It made me suspect that PHP 7.3 was not supported.